# How do you create a curved sequence of vertices?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I am trying to get the vertex that is highlighted and the two on it's left side and right side to be curved as seen with many of the ones done on the left. I have been manually doing it but I feel as though there should be an easier way to make more perfect curves.

[image: Image of how I have it setup]
[I have tried using a bezel but when doing so it doesn't ever do anything.](https://i.gyazo.com/8666bc4064f933611de0d7d15e5f6449.mp4)

I was also tried creating a path and then joining the two objects but that gave me the error "no mesh data to join"

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: How about using *actual Bezier Curve* objects, if you want to draw *curves*? You mention using but then proceed to link to an unrelated video of beveling

Comment: Sorry, I had a bunch of tabs open on different things that I was trying and I meant to type bezel but I typed Bezier Curve because when I swapped tabs to doublecheck I was using the right word I went to the wrong tab.

Comment: If using bezier curve, make sure to choose the correct spline type to start. You can block out the main start and end points of a curve with poly handle, and then switch to bezier to then stretch and arc your curves to match the shape you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a mesh object, select the single vertex and use Ctrl + B to start the bevel, and in the Operator Panel (F6 for popup) tick the option 'Vertex Only' and then increase the number of Segments to get a nice curve. 
Here I have completed this process on a simple plane with the face deleted so as to imitate your scenario.
[image]
After, you can turn on Proportional Edit with 'O' and use the MMB to increase/decrease influence and move the vertices around to shape them.

Comment: Thank you! This will do quite well! Also for the record, the face is not deleted, I had it in wireframe because I have a background image I was somewhat following. I just hid it for the image as to not make things messy.

Comment: @DragonHeart000 for tracing background images consider using inkscape, illustrator or other vector drawing programs that can do auto-trace of bitmap images. You can then save the vectors as SVG and import those into blender. It might save you a lot of time.

Comment: Didn't know that I could do that. That would for sure save a lot of time for some of the ones I do. What I had here was just a rough sketch of the idea and was polishing it up here but I have done some exact tracing by hand before and knowing this would for sure save me some time. I'll try it out next time I trace something exactly.

Comment: Depending on the image  on auto trace - if the image is a solid color and you can get the corners as sharp as you need, then that might be okay, but my experience is that auto trace has a tendency to be inaccurate and noisy as far as curve points go. Some of us prefer the way blender curves handle compared to vector editors.